# Calculate Hazard Ratio Manually for Continous Covariate

Tags: hazard

I found an example for manually calculating the hazard ratio when there are two groups.

```
d2 <- c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
d <- c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
r2 <- c(21, 19, 17, 16, 14, 12, 12, 12, 8, 8, 6, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1)
r1 <- c(21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 17, 16, 15, 13, 13, 12, 11, 11, 10, 7, 6)
l <- log(r2/r1)
d1 <- d - d2
dd <- cbind(d2, d1)
summary(glm(dd ~ offset(l), family = binomial))
```

where d is the number of deaths in total, and $d_i$ is the deaths in group $i$ and $r_j$ is the number of people in risk group $j$. I understand how this works.

I would like to do a similar exercise for when there are not two groups of people, but only one vector of continuous data (e.g. expression of a particular gene) and no grouping factor. How can it be done for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure can be approximated by binning the samples into groups of similar size, and doing a logistic regression on the number of events in each bin against the mean value of the independent variable in each bin.